# Is there a performance difference between EXECUTE ('CALL SCHEMA.PROC'), CALL SCHEMA.PROC, and EXCEUTE

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, query-optimization, dynamic-sql, hana

Is there a performance different between the three options, assuming the below query structure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.PROC
BEGIN
TEMP = SELECT * FROM A JOIN B JOIN C;
INSERT INTO TABLE (TEMP);
END;
```

Option 1:

```
STRING_OF_PROC = 'CALL SCHEMA.PROC()';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (STRING_OF_PROC);
```

Option 2:

```
CALL SCHEMA.PROC();
```

Option 3:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( TEMP = SELECT * FROM A JOIN B JOIN C; 
                    INSERT INTO TABLE (TEMP); );
```

*If it differs between different RDBMS, I am working in the SAP HANA space.*

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the question is rather vague, so my answer will just describe the different options and what follows from that.

Option 0: this is a stored procedure that performs a SELECT and tries to INSERT the result into a table.

Option 1: A string is prepared that contains the text for `CALL procedure()`, that string is then used with the dynamic SQL execution `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Option 2: a direct call of the procedure.

Option 3: an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` call with a block of SQLScript commands.

Ad option 3 simply won't work at all and lead to an error since `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` expects a command *string*. This command string needs to be correct SQL, which is not the case here. Also, it can only be a single command, not a list of multiple commands.

As options 1 and 2: these are nearly identical from a performance point of view. Clearly, the dynamic SQL option requires additional parsing and probably lead to additional entries in the shared SQL cache, but that should be a negligible part of the overall runtime of the procedure call.

BTW: the procedure in Option 0 is also not working - the procedure is syntactically wrong in several places.

Bottom line: the difference in performance between dynamic SQL call and direct call for the call of a single procedure without parameters or return values is likely to be negligible.